# Meteor POST repeated after two minutes

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to maintain a Meteor project which basically works as an entry data for a MongoDB database. When inserting a new record by clicking the *Add/Update* button a POST is submitted to the server and a new entry is created in MongoDB. So far so good.

```
POST /add_record HTTP/1.1 (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
```

The problem is this same POST is submitted again after exactly two minutes without any user action, and therefore the same record is created again. This happens three or four times.
Why is that and how can I avoid it?

Server code:

```js
Records = new Meteor.Collection("records");

Meteor.startup(function() {
   Meteor.publish('records', function() {
      return Records.find()
   });
});

Router.route('/add_record', function() {
   if (this.request.method == 'POST') {
      data = this.request.body;
      Records.update({_id:data.id}, { created_at:(new Date()).getTime() , name:data.name, value:data.value}, {upsert:true});
   }
},{where:'server'});
```

Client code:

```html
<head>
   <title>Meteortest</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="outer">
      {{> meteortest}}
   </div>
</body>

<template name="meteortest">
   <div class="meteortest">
      <div id="group">
          <input type="hidden" id="record_id">
          <input type="text" id='record_name'>
          <input type="text" id="record_value">
          <input type='button' id="add_record" value="Add/Update Record">
          <table>
             {{#each records}}
               <tr>{{> record}}</tr>
             {{/each}}
          </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<template name="record">
   <div class="record {{selected}}">
      <td>{{name}}:&nbsp;{{value}}</td>
   </div>
</template>
```

```js
Records = new Meteor.Collection("records");

Router.route('/', function() {
   this.render('');
});

Meteor.subscribe('records');

Template.meteortest.helpers({
   records: function() {
      return Records.find({}, {sort:{created_at:-1}})
   }
});

Template.meteortest.rendered = function() {
   $("#add_record").click(function() {
      $.post("/add_record",
        {id:$("#record_id").val(), name:$("#record_name").val(), value:$("#record_value").val()  });
      $("#record_name").val("");
      $("#record_value").val("");
   });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make your insert a Meteor method instead of a server route?

Comment: @chazsolo It's somebody else code and it is in production, that's why I prefer not to do significant changes.

Comment: Fair enough - but a problem severe enough will warrant a significant change. Could you try moving the `click` handler found within the `rendered` function of the template to a helper? It seems like you may be inadvertently attaching multiple handlers to `#add_record`.